# IDesktopWallpaper AdvanceSlideshow implementation

Tags: c#, windows, com

Im trying to advance the background slideshow on Windows 10 using the IDesktopWallpaper exposed in COM.

[Here is the description of that native class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706947(v=vs.85).aspx)

I am using the ComImport method described [here](https://github.com/xupefei/Bing-Wallpaper/blob/master/BingWallpaper/DesktopWallpaper.cs).

My code :

```
var wallpaper = new DesktopWallpaperClass();
for (uint i = 0; i < wallpaper.GetMonitorDevicePathCount(); i++)
{
    try
    {
        string path = wallpaper.GetMonitorDevicePathAt(i);
        wallpaper.AdvanceSlideshow(path, DesktopSlideshowDirection.Forward);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {}
}
```

But the call to AdvanceSlideShow errors with an exception

```
"The method or operation is not implemented"
```

Does this mean it cannot work at all?
If not, how can I make it advance the slideshow?

Comment: That's what I get as well on Win10 version 1607.  All other methods are okay, although Enable() is declared wrong.  Gets a bit more interesting when passing null as the first argument.  Well, doesn't work anymore, you'll need help from Microsoft to get ahead.

Comment: Good call on the null. That is wierd. The signature for path must not be a string... hmm

Answer (score 0):

The implementation missing seems to make some sense actually.

You can only ever advance the slideshow on any monitor by advancing it, regardless of how many monitors you have it will advance through them like a set. So there is no point in having a monitorId specified, as the slideshow is rolling through a set of images, the monitors are not freely associable.

All this flies in the face of the idea that the slideshow can not also proceed in a reverse direction. But, it seems the idea is that since the slideshow is set to shuffle, the backward direction is just not stored.

So we are stuck with an abstract set of images, the set advantage of which is lost due to shuffle.

Oh well.